# Why does the same button need different element locators to work?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, katalon-recorder

I'm new in Web Automation and I want to start with a simple question.

I'm working with Selenium Webdriver in Chrome.
I have a button on every page I test:

```
<button class="next_btn btn green">Btn</button>
```

The first time I had to write the  following syntax to get it working:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Btn')]")).click();
```

Other xpaths didn't work. Next time I had to use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'formtop\']/div/form/div/fieldset[2]/div[2]/button[2]")).click();
```

And the same button on the next page won't accept anything.

I tried:

```
WebElement stupidBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'formtop\']/div/form/div/fieldset[3]/div[2]/button[2]"));
stupidBtn.click();


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'formtop\']/div/form/div/fieldset[3]/div[2]/button[2]")).click();


WebElement stupidBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'formtop\']/div/form/div/fieldset[3]/div[2]/button[2]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", stupidBtn);


WebElement stupidBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@id=\'formtop\']/div/form/div/fieldset[3]/div[2]/button[2]"));
Actions buildAct = new Actions(driver);
buildAct.moveToElement(stupidBtn).click(stupidBtn);
buildAct.perform();


driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#formtop>div>form>div>fieldset:nth-child(3)>div.multiform_buttons>button.next_btn.btn.green")).click();
```

In general I want to know what I'm not understanding and why I can't use always the same syntax like in Katalon Automation Recorder. Unfortunately KAR isn't able to cover up all my needs.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Can you give us the url ?

Comment: It's possible all the buttons that you cannot locate are in an iframe.  If you're saying that the HTML code for each button is identical, and you are able to locate the first one, then that's the likely culprit.

Comment: @Rajagopalan
https://www.whats2doo.com/en/
I'm currently testing the Helper and ToDo settings. You need an account for that. Thank you and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you describe may happen if the "pages" you're talking about are not real page transitions, but each "next button" press is dynamically updating the same page.

I've seen multiple "multi-page" forms in the past that are all on the same page, but show and hide different "pages" depending on which section of the form a user is on.

So when you attempt to use the first locator on the second button, it still locates the first, attempts to interact with it, and throws an exception that the element is not visible/able to be interacted with.

In the past I've built solutions for this based on using findElements and then looping those elements to click the one that is currently displayed.

```
ArrayList<WebElement> elements = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Btn')]"));
for(WebElement element : elements) {
    if(element.isDisplayed()) {
        element.click();
    }
}
```

Without seeing the page I can't say whether this is definitely the case, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. You are totally right. The buttons have the same class but are in different fieldsets. Unfortunately your smart solution won't work either. And I forgot to tell something. Before pressing the button I choose a date in a jquery calendar. That works fine and I have tried not to interact with the calendar before calling the button. nothing changed. But now I have some ideas I will test. thanks again and regards

Answer (score 0):

Query if the class "next_btn" only links to that button alone, then you know it's a reliable unique locator for that element. In which case I suggest you refer directly to that class directly to get the element you are looking for, like so...

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".next_btn")).click();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you.
This doesn't work either. It's definitly a reliable unique locator. I wondering about the fact, that i can't use the same locator every time. And I forgot to tell something. Before pressing the button I choose a date in a jquery calendar. That works fine and I have tried to work with the two following things before calling the button:

driver.switchTo().window("WindowName");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

regards

Answer (score 0):

To be able to catch the button and make it work you need to see DOM in your Web Browser and check if you are putting the correct xpath.
The HTML in every page can differ from the others that's why selenium can't find the button and Selenium check your DOM to see the element and if it exists so you can have your button.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I'm using cropath, ranorex selocity, xpath helper and sideex for pathing. And I always look that the element is one out of one. Did I something wrong there or are there better ways/tools? regards

Answer (score 0):

I tried some different xpaths. e.g.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='formtop']//form[@class='multiform']/div/fieldset[3]//button[.='Weiter']")).click();
```

The button is definitely pressed (changed color), but the site isn't updating (manuel click works fine).

Finally this worked for me:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='formtop']/div/form/div/fieldset[3]/div[2]/button[2]")).click();
```

I don't know what was going wrong here. Maybe I forgot something little or there was a typo.

Thank you all and regards.